# jQuery .val() always returns true even when false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a boolean based on the value of an input inside a form, but I always keep ending up with either `true` or `undefined`. Where am I going wrong, and how do I get this right?

The value for `name=locations` will either be `''` if there are no locations, or a json array like `['SFO','SJO','LA']` etc.

```
<form id="locale">
    <input name="locations[]" value=''/>
</form>

if($("#locale input[name=locations]").val() !== '') {
    alert ($("#locale input[name=locations]").val());
} else {
    alert ('No locations for this item!');
}
```

Comment: `document.forms['locale']['locations[]'].value` is only one more character to type and is [*hugely faster*](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-pojs-form-control-value-access). ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of the input is `locations[]` not `locations`

```
$('#locale input[name="locations[]"]').val()
```

so

```
var value = $('#locale input[name="locations[]"]').val();
if (value !== '') {
    alert(value);
} else {
    alert('No locations for this item!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The removal of the brackets is for input names is PHP behaviour. As far as the client and the front end is concerned, if the input name has brackets, then the input name has brackets.

```
if($("#locale input[name='locations[]']").val() !== '') {
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the begins with match: `[name^=locations]`